# Skype has stopped working on Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1

Tags: skype, firewall, ubuntu-studio

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQklk.jpg) is what Skype displays when I try to connect.

I've tried reinstalling, but still no fix. When I sign in on my mobile phone it works, so I know it's an issue affecting only the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade skype to version 4.3.0.37.

Comment: Skype is not available for Ubuntu 14.04+

Comment: @fatboytall1: Yes it is. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: I meant the latest version of skype which you are referring.

Comment: It is, I have it.

Comment: @fatboytall1: If you say a little more than "is not available" we might be able to help you.

Comment: I downloaded the dynamic version from the skype website, as there is no DEB file for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, but that just runs version 4.2.

Comment: @fatboytall1: If you want it from the Skype website, select the "Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)" option. It works on 14.04 as well. Or you can install it from the Canonical Partner repository.